# blockquote-reverse не срабатывает

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Всем привет. 
Почему то в коде не срабатывает *reverse* часть класса blockquote, и выравнивание идет по левому краю, хотя ожидаю справа.

использую https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

```html
<div class="container">
    <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente nesciunt unde repellendus doloremque tenetur dignissimos omnis aut illum quasi labore.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">John the Fon</footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
```

*в чем может быть подвох?*

Comment: спасибо, добавлял, но не помогает (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Всё работает.

Просто вы немножко неправильно указали класс.*

Решение для **Bootstrap 4**.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

  <blockquote class="blockquote text-right">
    <p class="mb-0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
    <footer class="blockquote-footer">Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></footer>
  </blockquote>

</div>
```

Решение для **Bootstrap 3**.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

  <blockquote class="blockquote-reverse">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
    <footer>Someone famous in <cite>Source Title</cite></footer>
  </blockquote>

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, помог text-right. Просто смотрю курс на udemy, там работают с bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6, и там оперируют с reverse. Кажись в этой версии альфы был актуален еще reverse.

Comment: @zhanbau, возможно и был. Надо посмотреть в документации =)